# Rails ActiveRecord query working locally, but different result on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

My Rails 5 app works exactly as expected on my local environment with SQLite3, but when I deployed it to Heroku and it works with no errors, but some things aren't being displayed the same way. I think I've tracked it down to the following ActiveRecord query in my jobs controller:

```
@jobs_later = current_user.jobs.joins(:stage).where("stage_id != ? AND next_step_date > ?", 5, Date.today).order(:next_step_date, stage_id: :desc)
```

The query grabs a list of jobs belonging to the current user and displays some information about them in the view using the instance variable @jobs_later.

Here is the SQL from my local env:

```
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Job Exists (2.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(2.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "stages" ON "stages"."id" = "jobs"."stage_id" WHERE "jobs"."user_id" = ? AND (stage_id != 5 AND next_step_date > '2017-01-31')  [["user_id", 1]]

Job Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "stages" ON "stages"."id" = "jobs"."stage_id" WHERE "jobs"."user_id" = ? AND (stage_id != 5 AND next_step_date > '2017-01-31') ORDER BY "jobs"."next_step_date" ASC, "jobs"."stage_id" DESC  [["user_id", 1]]

Step Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "steps".* FROM "steps" WHERE "steps"."job_id" = ? ORDER BY "steps"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["job_id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]

CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "steps".* FROM "steps" WHERE "steps"."job_id" = ? ORDER BY "steps"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["job_id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Stage Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "stages".* FROM "stages" WHERE "stages"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

And here's the SQL from Postgres on Heroku:

```
2017-01-31T14:24:54.842062+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-01-31T14:24:54.841973 #4] DEBUG -- : [19703b11-bfbb-4c6f-99b6-b617853ee65a]   User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2017-01-31T14:24:54.858947+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-01-31T14:24:54.858813 #4]  INFO -- : [19703b11-bfbb-4c6f-99b6-b617853ee65a]   Rendering jobs/index.html.erb within layouts/application

2017-01-31T14:24:54.867244+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-01-31T14:24:54.867099 #4] DEBUG -- : [19703b11-bfbb-4c6f-99b6-b617853ee65a]   Job Exists (6.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2017-01-31T14:24:54.786697+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/jobs/1" host=agile-lowlands-76952.herokuapp.com request_id=5d33ac27-2f26-495e-8261-0d0050723aa6 fwd="173.48.208.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=159ms status=302 bytes=1073

2017-01-31T14:24:54.904549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/jobs" host=agile-lowlands-76952.herokuapp.com request_id=19703b11-bfbb-4c6f-99b6-b617853ee65a fwd="173.48.208.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=77ms status=200 bytes=3454

2017-01-31T14:24:54.883387+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-01-31T14:24:54.883287 #4] DEBUG -- : [19703b11-bfbb-4c6f-99b6-b617853ee65a]    (3.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "stages" ON "stages"."id" = "jobs"."stage_id" WHERE "jobs"."user_id" = $1 AND (stage_id != 5 AND next_step_date > '2017-01-31')  [["user_id", 1]]
```

You'll notice that locally it goes through the job User Load, Job Exists, Job Load, Step Load, and Stage Load steps.

But in production it goes through User Load, Job Exits, and then stops. Not sure what the heroku[router] steps are in between or if that has anything to do with it.

I've also checked the postgres db and the data has been entered correctly, so it's not as if it's coming up empty.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not surprisingly, this had an obvious answer. When I deployed to Heroku, I didn't run `heroku run rails db:seed` so when the SQL in my controller ran, it tried to reference tables that had no data in them. When I checked my tables before, I didn't think to check the ones I was seeding.